# C# item isn't in List, and not null or whitespace

Tags: c#, while-loop, whitespace, isnullorempty

Hello!
We're working on a program where you can create new 'folders' and upload files to them.
The problem is, I want to make that inside a Folder, it is not allowed to create two subfolder with the same name.
Here's my code.

```
while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderName) || !foglalt || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(folderName))
{
    folderName = Console.ReadLine();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderName) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(folderName))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ez a mező nem lehet üres. \nÚj mappa neve:");
        //(Can't be null. \nNew foldername:)
        break;
    }

    if (p.FolderList.Contains(folderName))
    {
        foglalt = true;
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Ez a mappanév egyszer már szerepel ebben a környezetben. Kérlek válassz újat!\nÚj mappa neve:");
        //(That name is already taken. \nNew foldername:)
    }
    else {foglalt = false;}
}
```

("foglalt" is a bool, means taken.)
There must be something wrong in the while condition, but i just don't know what.
Could you please help me fix this?

Comment: When i give it a name that elready exist, it works, when i give it whitespace or null it works, but when i type something that would be good, it just keep asking me for another names.

Comment: So what do you *expect* it to do? Can you provide a [mcve] instead of just this snippet? (Ideally, change all the variable names and messages into English, for the sake of future readers.)

Comment: So you want to keep trying to get a valid folder name until the user gives one?

Comment: @lamandy exactly. but when the user gives a valid foldername the program doesnt do anything, just keep asking for a foldername

Comment: Hint: look at your while condition - it says "While "the folder name isn't empty, or the folder name is empty". How could that condition *ever* be false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (true)
{
    folderName = Console.ReadLine();

    // if folder name is null or empty or whitespace, ask for a new folder name
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderName) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(folderName))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ez a mező nem lehet üres. \nÚj mappa neve:");
        //(Can't be null. \nNew foldername:)
    }
    //if folder name already exists, ask for a new one
    else if (p.FolderList.Contains(folderName))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ez a mappanév egyszer már szerepel ebben a környezetben. Kérlek válassz újat!\nÚj mappa neve:");
        //(That name is already taken. \nNew foldername:)
    }
    else //Folder Name is valid
        break; //proceed to do stuff with the folder name
}
//Do my stuff with the valid folder name
```

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't like the "while(1)" it say "cannot convert type int to bool"

Comment: change 1 to true then

Comment: @Skickpause Just 1 extra advice, instead of checking like this, try Directory.CreateDirectory instead for a more robust checking. The check above is not sufficient, there are cases such as user has no permission to access the folder, folder name has invalid characters, name is too long, etc. Read the example here in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This `string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderName) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(folderName)` is redundant. `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` of course checks also for empty string.